# Servlet ArrayList

Tags: java, servlets, web, arraylist

I've a problem to pass a ArrayList from servlet to servlet.

FIRST SERVLET

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
ArrayList users = new ArrayList();    
…
    request.setAttribute("list", utenti);
    RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/secondServlet");
    rd.forward(request, response);
    return;
```

SECOND SERVLET

```
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    ArrayList users = (ArrayList) session.getAttribute("list");
```

If now I use an Iterator to read single element I've as result that my ArrayList is null. 
I don't understand why I can't pass that.

Tanks

Comment: request.setAttribute() / session.getAttribute(). Guess what's wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to set the value into request and trying to read from the session.

To get the list, Read from the request.

Or, if you will require that list for the complete user session, set into the session.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Yadu's answer,

Do program to an interface.

Avoid

```
ArrayList users = new ArrayList();
```

Do

```
List users = new ArrayList();
```

even better

```
List<String> users = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Answer (score 0):

in FIRSTSERVLET try session instead request.

```
 session.setAttribute("list", utenti); 

RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/secondServlet");
rd.forward(request, response);
return;
```